# Array sorting with orders by values

Tags: arrays, sorting, java-8

I want to sort an array by two different orders.

In first-order, I want to put objects in one of the fields that belong to a certain list of statuses.
In second-order should be objects where another field is not null
In third-order rest.

So for example my object is:

```
public class CustomObject {

   private String status;
   private String name;
}
```

For this my implementation looks like this:

```
 List<String> statuses =  Arrays.asList("IN", "IF", "IR");
 List<CustomObject> firstOrder = new ArrayList<>();
 List<CustomObject> secondOrder = new ArrayList<>();
 List<CustomObject> rest = new ArrayList<>();
    
 for (CustomObject temp : notSortedList){
      if(temp.getStatus().equals(statuses.get(0)) || 
                temp.getStatus().equals(statuses.get(1)) || 
                temp.getStatus().equals(statuses.get(2))){
         firstOrder.add(temp);
      } else if(temp.getName()!= null){
         secondOrder.add(temp); 
      } else {
         rest.add(temp);
      }
}
List<CustomObject> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
sortedList.addAll(firstOrder);
sortedList.addAll(secondOrder);
sortedList.addAll(rest);
```

So my question is can I implement it using Comparator or some another Java 8 feature.

Comment: Why don’t you use `statuses.contains(temp.getStatus())` instead of that `temp.getStatus().equals(statuses.get(0)) ||  temp.getStatus().equals(statuses.get(1)) ||  temp.getStatus().equals(statuses.get(2))`?

Comment: @Holger yes you are correct, but it's just to explain my logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparator doing exactly the same as your code would be

```java
Comparator<CustomObject> c = Comparator.comparingInt(o ->
    statuses.contains(o.getStatus())? 0: o.getName() != null? 1: 2);
```

There’s also the feature of comparator chaining like

```java
Comparator<CustomObject> c = Comparator
    .comparing((CustomObject o) -> !statuses.contains(o.getStatus()))
    .thenComparing(o -> o.getName() == null);
```

which differs from your example code, as it would change the relative order of the elements contained in `firstOrder`, moving elements with a `null` name at the end of this sublist. But the three main groups are still as required, so if stable sorting is not required for the first group, this would work too.

When you have the comparator, you can use

```java
List<CustomObject> sortedList = notSortedList.stream()
    .sorted(c)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to get a new sorted list or

```java
notSortedList.sort(c);
```

to sort in-place.

---

Your logic also allows a variant of [Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), to sort all elements in O(n) time into a sorted list:

```java
int[] groups = new int[3];
for(CustomObject o: notSortedList)
    if(statuses.contains(o.getStatus())) groups[1]++;
    else if(o.getName() != null) groups[2]++;

groups[2] += groups[1];

List<CustomObject> sortedList = Arrays.asList(new CustomObject[notSortedList.size()]);
for(CustomObject o: notSortedList) sortedList.set(
    groups[statuses.contains(o.getStatus())? 0: o.getName() != null? 1: 2]++, o);
```

Comment: This exactly what i'm looking for. You just made small misstake  here: o -> o.getName() != null -- this should be "==". Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a series of streams here for a Java 8 option:

```
List<String> statuses = "IN|IF|IF";

List<CustomObject> firstOrder = notSortedList.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getStatus().matches(statuses))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<CustomObject> secondOrder = notSortedList.stream()
    .filter(x -> !x.getStatus().matches(statuses) &&
                 x.getName() != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<CustomObject> rest = notSortedList.stream()
    .filter(x -> !x.getStatus().matches(statuses) &&
                 x.getName() == null)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes it's better, but i'm want to use Comporator. Implementation above just for simply understand my question. Here you also create 3 different lists, and I want to avoid it.

Comment: @RomanB A comparator, by itself, is the wrong tool for this job.  You would use a comparator to take the input `notSortedList` and arrange/order the list elements in a certain order.  But, in your case, you actually want to separate out the items into three different lists.  Streams with filters are an appropriate tool for this job.

Comment: i'm find something like this but cant setup for my case: Arrays.sort(bookArray, Comparator.comparing(Book::getName)
      .thenComparing(Book::getAuthor))
      .thenComparingInt(Book::getId));

Comment: No i not need 3 separate arrays. i need 1 with correct order of element's in my question in result you see the sortedList.